# How to add decimal separators to numbers in certain fields

Tags: awk

I have a .txt file and I need to add commas as decimal separators to improve the readability. Those long numbers only exist in certain columns and I couldn't find a way to do that. The columns are separated by semicolons and can contain any character. I thought about using an if statement in awk to check if the length of those columns are bigger than 3, but then I couldn't find a way to put the commas in between every three digits. 
The numbers are in the third and fourth columns.

This

```
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30275;28686;v2.0 beta (1998-03-17);Cyberbit.ttf (12.4 MB);Bitstream CyberCJK;Medium (Normal), Book, Roman;TTF;Cove

Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21957;57621;v13.00 sfnt rev 5 Pen-Ji (2010-08-24);YOzRN.TTC (13.5 MB);YOzFontN;Regular;TTC;Any
```

should turn into this:

```
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30,275;28,686;v2.0 beta (1998-03-17);Cyberbit.ttf (12.4 MB);Bitstream CyberCJK;Medium (Normal), Book, Roman;TTF;Cove

Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21,957;57,621;v13.00 sfnt rev 5 Pen-Ji (2010-08-24);YOzRN.TTC (13.5 MB);YOzFontN;Regular;TTC;Any
```

Comment: The number are always 5 digits long?

Comment: No, they can be shorter or longer

Comment: Actually, I checked the file and the numbers are either 4 or 5 digit long.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `numfmt` from GNU Coreutils, and your locale supports such grouping, you could use:

```
numfmt -d ';' --field=- --grouping --invalid='ignore' < file
```

Ex.

```
$ numfmt -d ';' --field=- --grouping --invalid='ignore' < file
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30,275;28,686;v2.0 beta (1998-03-17);Cyberbit.ttf (12.4 MB);Bitstream CyberCJK;Medium (Normal), Book, Roman;TTF;Cove

Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21,957;57,621;v13.00 sfnt rev 5 Pen-Ji (2010-08-24);YOzRN.TTC (13.5 MB);YOzFontN;Regular;TTC;Any
```

If you know which fields contain the numeric fields, you can specify them explicitly and omit the `--invalid` handling:

```
numfmt -d ';' --field=3,4 --grouping < file
```

---

If you have GNU awk, you can do a similar thing using the `%'` format modifier with `sprintf`:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {OFS=FS=";"} 
  {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) $i = sprintf("%'\''d", $i)}} 
  1
' file
```

Comment: Can it be done by awk, I don't have GNU awk